# Transparent Data Encryption on Shared database in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, transparent-data-encryption

Things seem to have changed over time with this - I know it used to be the case that this was only possible on a dedicated database for example. I've worked on an account on a shared database that did not need an MID change (something I understood would be required). Does this mean that the database it sits on already has TDE enabled?

And if so, does this mean that all tenants on the database share the same encryption key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined here "[Data at Rest Encryption](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_data_encryption.htm&type=5)"

> You can use this feature in these situations.
>
> Shared environment where multiple customers share a multi-tenant data environment
> Dedicated data environment used to host your data (as an optional add-on feature)

There is no clarity on if they use the same keys or not, but I would imagine each DB would have their own.